# To create user and a group using Go Lang. But the Go Binary must be executed only for a specific user

Tags: go

I have a Go Binary, which when executed will create a User and a Group.

But now I want this Go Binary to be executed only for a specific user?

Is it possible? If yes, how can I achieve this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you want. Maybe you can tell us an example story of what should happen and why?

Comment: I'm using CentOS 7. If I run my Go lang code, it must create one user and its group. Is this posssible?

Comment: I think you were looking for an utility script execution, changing the script permission does the job. Like chmod 500 <executable>. Also you can execute all shell commands from golang.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But you still have to answer why a simple `useradd` does not serve you well. Tell us more about the whole story and its surrounding.

Comment: Please elaborate on the "to be executed only for a specific user" bit. Do you want your program to be somehow executable only by a specific system user? Or do you mean you want to somehow pass the name of the user and group for your program to create in the system? It's okay if English is not your native language; just write down your requirements in a few sentences. It helps to just spell out the *intended* outcome of your program, and how you intend to run it. Like 1) I run my program; 2) It does such and such; 3) In the result I have this and that...

Answer (score 0):

you can call the binary and pass a parameter specifying the use and then you in your code you check if you want to continue or not. i.e:

the first thing in your main function:

```
func main(){
    if os.Args[1]!="your specific user"{
         fmt.Println("code will not be executed for this user")
         return

    } 
    //continue what you want to do



}
```

then build your project, and call it like `./project user`